# Kate editor works really slow, on FTP

Tags: ftp, ubuntu-mate, kate

I am using Ubuntu MATE, latest version. I am browsing FTP with Caja. My text editor is Kate.

The problem is Kate is really slow over FTP. When I am opening a file by FTP, it takes around 5-10 seconds to open, then it is blocked for a lot of time, and after that I am able to insert a character (but I must wait for each, around 1-2 seconds to see it typed). That's not happening with local files.

Using system's default text editor (xed), FTP files are opening almost instantly and working great.

What could be the problem and how can I solve? I need kate because of some features.